# How to sync draft emails via EWS API 2.0

Tags: synchronization, exchangewebservices

I use EWS API 2.0. And try to sync draft emails from Drafts via SyncFolderItems.

I create new email in Outlook and saved it in Drafts. And this email returns in SyncFolderItems (in ItemChange like new email for Drafts(like it normally, ChangeType.Create)). Then I send this draft email from Outlook (from Drafts), and any ItemChange doesn't come in SyncFolderItems request. (I wait for ChangeType.Delete, but nothing comes)

Does anybody know how to detect if Draft email was sent from Drafts?

Comment: Have you implement SyncFolderItems for Sent folder ?

Comment: Yes, I have. And for Sent folder sent email comes like a new email (ChangeType.Create). And yes, I know that the draft and sent email has the same ItemId. But in this case each time when we will get new email in Sent folder we will need check it ItemId with saved ItemIds in db. It bad for perfomance and I try to know exist another way for detect this situation or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was resolved. 
 Problem because of two concurrent synchronizations running.